# Use a variable with extends in Djano

Tags: python, html, django

I want to create a Django project with dynamic template (theme). I defined my active template name in setting.py like below.

```
# GLOBAL VARIABLE FOR TEMPLATE
ACTIVE_TEMPLATE = "presento"
```

I want to use this variable in my project. For example, when I use this variable in extends, I get an error like this.

```
{% extends "frontend/{{ACTIVE_TEMPLATE}}/base/base.html" %}
```

This is the error.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

frontend/{{ACTIVE_TEMPLATE}}/base/base.html
```

What is your advice to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% extends "frontend/"|add:ACTIVE_TEMPLATE|add:"/base/base.html" %}
```